# How to decode the hl7 message in to a normal text

Tags: .net, hl7, nhapi

I am new to this HL7 messages and started working on them today. I hav gone though some of the tutorials and videos over web

[corepoint](http://www.corepointhealth.com/resource-center/hl7-resources)

[HL7Soup](http://hl7soup.com/HL7TutorialUnderstandingHL7MessageStructure.html)

I have understood that there is certain format that the messages will be transformed across HIS. I want to know whether we can actually decode the messages into a text by using some tool or an API. Im more convenient with .NET related things if there are any but anything that are available would do though. I have tried nHapi API for .NET but i am not sure which api methods i should use

Answer (score 2):

[MSDN: Microsoft BizTalk → Programming Guide → Processing HL7 Messages → Message Encodings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee409267.aspx) provides some overview of the `pipe and hat` and `xml` message formats.

The most correct source of information are specification documents which you can download for free from [hl7.org](http://www.hl7.org/implement/standards/product_section.cfm?section=1&ref=nav) website.

As for the `nhapi` tutorials and cook books, you can study what's available for [hapi](http://hl7api.sourceforge.net/) and then transfer your `Java` knowledge to `C#`.